# Magento 2 save Category programmatically

Tags: magento, magento2

I am new to Magento 2.

I have override the category class `vendor/magento/module-visual-merchandiser/Model/Rules.php`. But when i try to save the category using the following code

```
$categoryId = 6;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $currentCategory = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
            ->load($categoryId);
        $currentCategory->setStoreId(0);
        $this->_logger->addDebug($currentCategory->getName());
        $currentCategory->setIsActive(1);
        try {
            $currentCategory->save();
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $this->_logger->addDebug($e->getMessage());
        }
```

It is not calling my overriden class still it is calling the original/parent class.

Comment: Could you please share your complete module code including all xml files

Comment: @SachinS We need to add the <preference for="Magento\VisualMerchandiser\Model\Rules" type="Eguana\CategoryCustomRules\Model\Rewrite\VisualMerchandiser\Rules" /> in di.xml and second also flush cache, var/generation folder.